# vuejs update all components when state changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I use vuex for state management. Let's say i Have n components using the vuex to access the data. All the n components are using the state and have bound to the view. So I want to know if component1 changes the state, let's say remove a particular element, how can I trigger the the n-1 components to update the view with the regarding state. Can it done with the computed function or is there an other more efficient way to update the views with the correspondent state.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### using computed

as you mentioned the clean way is to use computed property. within the functions you can access `this.$store.state` and change the behaviour of component `n+1` depending on `n`.

### including changes in action

another way would be that your action simply triggers mutations for element `n` and `n+1`.

### styling related changes

just to mention it, when you want a component to be conditionally displayed or styled, it is often enough to set a class on the modified component `n` and using conditional styling based on this class to style `n+1`.

Comment: alright I see. So my concerns were right. I am not sure which approach is the cleanest of all the alternatives. Than you.